# LU- and UL-Factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, matrix-decomposition

I am struggling to understand the following problem

> Consider the $n\times n$ matrix:
>
> $$
> M(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}
>        m_{11} & m_{12} & \cdots & m_{1.n-1} & x\\
>        m_{21} & m_{22}&&m_{2,n-1}&m_{2,n}\\
>        \vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
>        m_{n-1,1}&m_{n-1,2} &&m_{n-1,n-1}&m_{n-1,n}\\
>        y & m_{n,2} & \cdots &m_{n,n-1}& m_{n.n}
>      \end{bmatrix}.
> $$
>
> Find necessary and sufficient conditions on the entries $m_{ij}$ such that $M(x,y)$ admits LU- and UL-factorization and for all $i,j$ if $|i-j| > 1$ then $(M(x,y)^{-1})_{ij}=0$, i.e. the inverse is a 1-band matrix, for some complex numbers $x$ and $y$. *In this case find such $x,y$.*

I found out that if $M(x,y)$ is invertible, then it admits an LU factorization if and only if all its leading principal minors are nonzero [[1 ]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Existence_and_uniqueness), where leading principal minors are defined as

**Def:** The leading k-th order principal sub-matrix of $M$ is the $k\times k$ matrix obtained by deleting the last $n-k$ rows and columns. The k-th order leading principal minor is its determinant.

So, I observe that 
$$
\det(m_{11}),\quad \det(\begin{bmatrix} m_{11}&m_{12}\\ m_{21}&m_{22}\end{bmatrix}),\quad\ldots\quad , \det\begin{bmatrix}
       m_{11} & m_{12} & \cdots & m_{1.n-1} & x\\
       m_{21} & m_{22}&&m_{2,n-1}&m_{2,n}\\
       \vdots &\vdots &\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
       m_{n-1,1}&m_{n-1,2} &&m_{n-1,n-1}&m_{n-1,n}\\
       y & m_{n,2} & \cdots &m_{n,n-1}& m_{n.n}
     \end{bmatrix}
$$

are the 1st,2nd,...,nth order leading principal minors.

Here I get stuck. So, I thought it would be a good idea to reduce the dimension to get a simpler form.

> consider the $3\times 3$ matrix 
>   $$
> A(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&x\\ a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\ y&a_{32}&a_{33} \end{bmatrix}
> $$

The 1st, 2nd and 3rd order leading principle minors are:

$$
a_{11}\\
a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21} \tag{1}\\
-a_{11} a_{23} a_{32}+a_{22} a_{11} a_{33}-a_{12} a_{21} a_{33}+a_{12} a_{23} y+a_{21} a_{32} x-a_{22} x  y
$$

So, if $\det(A(x,y))\not =0$, then its invertible. And if equations (1) are nonzero, then  $A(x,y)$  admits an LU factorization (according to the theorem).

The inverse of $A(x,y)$ will have the following form
$$
\frac{1}{det(A(x,y))} \begin{bmatrix}a_{22} a_{33}-a_{23} a_{32} & a_{32} x-a_{12} a_{33} & a_{12} a_{23}-a_{22} x \\
a_{23} y-a_{21} a_{33} & a_{11} a_{33}-x y & a_{21} x-a_{11} a_{23} \\
a_{21} a_{32}-a_{22} y & a_{12} y-a_{11} a_{32} & a_{11} a_{22}-a_{12} a_{21}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Therefore, to get 1-bandness, i.e. if $|i-j| > 1$ then $(A(x,y)^{-1})_{ij}=0$, we let
$$
a_{12} a_{23}-a_{22} x =0\\
a_{21} a_{32}-a_{22} y=0
$$

and obtain $x=a_{12} a_{23}/a_{22}$ and $y=a_{21} a_{32}/a_{22}$. However,

> **I am not able to find (explicitly) necessary and sufficient conditions on the entries and hence I fail to find complex numbers $x$ and $y$. Is there an alternative method to solve this? How can I finish this proof**

Any hints are appreciated.